# Are there Wizard alternatives to Arcane Bond and Familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, class-feature

My player don't want to use this mechanic because he believes that it make his character vulnerable.

His PC in my opinion now is much more weaker.

Is there any mechanic that I can use instead Arcane Bond or Familiar for his wizard or he must choose one of those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, yes, there are a large number of wizard archetypes that replace the Arcane Bond ability with something else.  See [the table for Wizard archetypes on the d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Archetypes-Alternate-Class-Features).  All but one of the Paizo core archetypes (Arcane Bomber, Primalist, Scrollmaster, Shadowcaster, Siege Mage, and Spellslinger) replace Arcane Bond, not to mention all three current racial archetypes and a long list of third party archetypes. Each replaces it with a flavorful ability relevant to that kind of archetype.

Answer (score 0):

If he really doesn't want either option, he can choose not to make use of them. But, by the rules as written in the Core rulebook, no, there is no standard option for substituting a power to replace them.

Nothing stops you from doing whatever you like in your own game, so you could simply provide a bonus feat of the PCs' choice to replace the arcane bond ability.

In addition, there are a handful of official Archetypes that replace Arcane Bond with another ability. These are scattered over a variety of sourcebooks. Several of them also significantly change the flavour of the Wizard class (i.e. Spellslinger, which uses guns, or the Scrollmaster, who is a close combat expert, but with Scrolls rather than normal weapons or armour), and a third of them require specific races to use.